# Retrive results based on conditions from multiple tables

Tags: sql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

This is a question on SQL query on Wordpress. I have a template that returns posts by Author. The author is primary for some posts and also assigned as secondary author for few other posts.

The result I wanted to achieve is that I would like to list all the posts where the author is assigned as both primary and secondary.

I have no clue about the sql query I should implement or is there a workaround on this. Kindly help.

Comment: How are the two authors set up? Are you making use of the WordPress Author for primary author, and the secondary author is a custom taxonomy? Or is it a completely separate table, not using WordPress's functionality?

Comment: The post meta table has the author with meta_key as second author, meta_value with user name. The second author is set by Co-author plus plugin. Its a free version and it doesnt do the job as expected.